# Exact sequence, coequalizer and existence of a morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, exact-sequence

I have a $R$ commutative ring and an exact sequence of $R$-modules

\begin{aligned}
0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow & ~~B \longrightarrow  D \longrightarrow  0 \\
& \uparrow \uparrow \\
&~D
\end{aligned}
I would like to know if there is a canonical morphism $D \rightarrow A$. At first, I thought I could do something with coeaqualizer but I did not succeed.
Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. Just to be clear -- Do either of the two maps $D \to B$ split the sequence? At the very least, do we know that we get the same map $D \to B \to D$ regardless of which $D \to B$ we pick?

Comment: We need to know _some_ information about these maps, since otherwise we can take $0 \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / 2 \to 0$ with two copies of the zero map from $\mathbb Z / 2 \to \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yeah sorry it is not precise enough I wanted to make it simple. So we have the same map regardless of which $D\rightarrow B$ we pick. One of these two maps is just the inclusion $ D \hookrightarrow B$ and I don't know what else to say.

Comment: sorry, but your question is still not clear to me either; you're saying that one of the maps $D\rightrightarrows B$ is an injection, but there's absolutely no condition on the other map? what's the point of having two maps from $D$ to $B$ then, when one of them could just be the zero map? also, what do you mean by "canonical morphism" $D\rightarrow A$? for instance, there is always the zero map from $D$ to $A$, for *any* modules $D$ and $A$, and this is certainly "canonical" in a certain sense. you need to be a bit more precise in what you're asking